# Создание разного количества DropDownlist в MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Грубо говоря, есть основная запись в БД (Processing), есть коллекция - к каким темам относится основная запись (EmailTheme). Для этого написаны следующие классы:

```
public class Processing
{
    public ICollection<EmailTheme> EmailThemes { get; set; }
}

public class EmailTheme
{
        public int ThemeId { get; set; }
}
```

Требуется: при открытии формы редактирования записи сформировать несколько DropDownList с уже выбранными значениями (ThemeId) + еще один лист для новой темы. Также есть еще вопрос - как реализовать создание такого же DDL при клике на кнопку "Добавить тему"?

P.S. ViewBag заполняется при загрузке вьюшки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При загрузке представления создаете несколько ViewBag в контроллере, которые содержат нужные данные:

напрмер:

```
ViewBag.Test = new SelectList(db.Test, "Id", "Name", Test);
```

после выводите их в представление:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Test")
```

Если кол-во DDL разное, то получаете коллекцию данных и уже в представлении через цикл создаете DDL при помощи простого HTML

Точно так же можно создать пустую, либо сделать это в представлении.

По поводу добавления новой проще всего Ajax запрос к контроллеру и добавление через частичное представление, если нужно получение данных от сервера. 
Если создается шаблонный список, то просто через JavaScript создаете в нужном месте.

Пример:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "saveconfirm" }))
{
}
```

и уже из контроллера возвращаете

```
return PartialView("_Test", TestSelectList);
```

Comment: а при сабмите формы эти листы уже будут сформированы как коллекция?